# How to disable dark mode in android 9

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am trying to disable dark mode in my app and its working on android 10 or higher but its not working on android 9. Can anyone please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

In on create method i have done below,
in theme or theme(night), in both files i placed

```
<style name="Theme.VideoTradieProvider" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
<!--    <style name="Theme.VideoTradieProvider" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">-->
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->

        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

<!--        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode_old</item>-->
<!--        <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode_old</item>-->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

also write below line but not working with anroid 9

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"`?

Comment: @TheLibrarian  yes, i have tried just now, but same issue occurring

Comment: How does the `onCreate` look like? (Do you call it before or after `super.onCreate()`)

Comment: after super.onCreate i called it sir.

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

Comment: Try calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Comment: i have tried below , but same problem coming.

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

Answer (score 1):

Change the parent attribute of your app style in themes.xml from

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it Right As **Josh** and another way to see if You have the theme(night) then delete it